# Pass javascript data to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html page with this code below that receives data from a server and after getting the data i want to send it over to a php so that i can use that data in a sql query and get the results of that query to send it back to my current html page.

```
var json = sessionStorage.xhr;
var object = JSON.parse(json);

var hard =  object["red-fruits"];
var string = JSON.stringify (hard);

var stringData = encodeURIComponent(string);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/web/main.php",
    data: {"dataA" : stringData}, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(){
        alert(stringData);
    }
});
```

This is my PHP page codes so in this page im trying to get the dataA and put it inside a query to get back an array which is the "$haha" and send it back over to my html page. I would like to ask if this logic is even possible to do without any form?

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","") or 
die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

if (isset($_POST['dataA']))
{
echo $name = $_POST['dataA'];
}
else
{
echo "Error";
}

$falcon = $_POST['dataA'];

$string = str_replace("]", "", str_replace("[", "", str_replace('"', 
'',$falcon)));
$array = explode(',', $string);
$array2= implode("', '",$array);

$sql = //SQL QUERY HERE;

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . 
mysqli_error($connection));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$haha[] =  $row['fruits'];
}
?>
```

Comment: You might want to look into [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) instead of all the str_replace shenanigans

Comment: `str_replace` can also take an array `str_replace(array('[', ']', '"'), ''`.

Comment: `this logic is even possible to do without any form?` It's possible you can do with `AJAX` like you did

Comment: @HoàngĐăng So my php page wont even need to be loaded? just used to recieve the data converting it and sending it back to the html page right

Comment: Right your page current will not refresh. It just wait the response from server

Comment: @HoàngĐăng Do you have any idea on how i would use the $haha array and send it back to the html page?

Comment: @NigelChuan just return it from your php, then client-side will catch it in ajax then you can use js to print it out in html